# Upload file to FTP server

Tags: android

I'm trying to upload a file to an FTP server with this code:

```
private void upload( String ftpServer, String user, String password,
            String fileName, File source ) throws MalformedURLException,
            IOException
    {
         if (ftpServer != null && fileName != null && source != null){
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer( "ftp://" );

            if (user != null && password != null){
               sb.append( user );
               sb.append( ':' );
               sb.append( password );
               sb.append( '@' );
            }

            sb.append( ftpServer );
            sb.append( '/' );
            sb.append( fileName );
            sb.append( ";type=i" );

            BufferedInputStream bis = null;
            BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
            try
            {
               URL url = new URL( sb.toString() );
               URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
                   urlc.setDoOutput(true);
               bos = new BufferedOutputStream( urlc.getOutputStream() );
               bis = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream( source ) );
               int i;
               while((i = bis.read()) != -1){
                      bos.write( i );
               }

            }
            finally
            {
               if (bis != null)
                  try
                  {
                     bis.close();
                  }
                  catch (IOException ioe)
                  {
                     ioe.printStackTrace();
                  }
               if (bos != null)
                  try
                  {
                     bos.close();
                  }
                  catch (IOException ioe)
                  {
                     ioe.printStackTrace();
                  }
            }
         }
         else{
            Log.e("Tag", "Input not available." );
         }
    }
```

But the file doesn't end up on the server.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can communicate with an FTP server in that way.
I recommend using the apache ftp client.

Download at
http://commons.apache.org/net/download_net.cgi

Documentation at
http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

The code looks correct but you must add a catch statement to handle exceptions and identify why the problem has occurred. Try making sure that you can at least get the output stream.

```
try
{
    //do some operation
    URL url = new URL(CONNECTION_URL);
    URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
    urlc.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStream outStream = urlc.getOutputStream();

}
catch(IOException ex)
{
    // ** your error information is in ex.getCause () **
}
finally
{
    //clean up
}
```

**Alternatively**

The alternative is to use the FTPClient call from apache, [Android - how to upload a file via FTP](http://hoang17.com/posts/android/android-how-to-upload-a-file-via-ftp) details some difficulties using your method and makes this same recommendation.  It also provides a good example of how to implement FTPclient in your code.